# Methods of a "belongs to" and "has many" relationships

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, entity-relationship

Let's say that I have two tables in my database:

```
users
countries
```

I have two defined relationships on each user `belongsTo` a country and each country `hasMany` users.. (**CakePHP** model relationships)

And I want to create the model `findUsersFromCountry($countryID)` in which class/model this method will be? It must be inside the `User` model or the `Country` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will your method return ? Or what kind of data will your method manipulate ?

If your method works on Users *(it does)*, I would have it in the `User` class.